# How to export a struct definition from a native C .dll for use in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c, interop, clr

I know how to extern methods in the .dll, how do I extern structs?

I want to create a C method such as

```
extern __declspec(dllexport) myStructure getStruct();
```

where myStructure is something like

```
typedef struct
{
   int A;
   int B;
   char C;
} myStructure;
```

How can I call getStruct() from a piece of C# code without first defining the same exact struct in C#? I want to keep a centralized declaration of myStructure so that I only have to make code changes in one place.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

What about doing it another way? Define the struct in [C# in T4](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx) and then cross gen to the new format in each of the projects:

**ie. base.tt**

// C# definition of struct

**in gencsharp.tt in the C# project**
include "base.tt"
... output the C#

**in gencplusplus.tt in the CPP project**
include "base.tt"
... use C# to gen a cpp .h file

Comment: And what if the struct comes from a third party library?

Comment: import the type into the template and reflect it in there?

Answer (score 1):

I've done a bit of P/Invoke with C# and I've always had to define structs in C# that correspond to the Win32 struct by definition.  The runtime uses the struct definition to marshal the data from unmanaged to managed.  Preet's answer is probably the best.